# Membership.GetUser().UserName; (.net 4, mvc 3)

Tags: .net, authentication

i log users into .net using straightforward .net authentication:

```
if ( Membership.ValidateUser( user, passwd ) )
```

works fine. hot on the heels of that, i try to get the user name:

```
Membership.GetUser().UserName
```

sometimes this will return an invalid object. sometimes not.
i cannot seem to detect a pattern as to which is which.

for example, a user logs in with a valid role in the system as 'root'/'password'.
the ValidateUser() call succeeds, but Membership.GetUser().UserName returns an invalid object.
2 seconds later, do the same exact thing again, and both the validate and the GetUser() succeed.

any ideas?

---

.. edit 1 ..
here's how i use the username:

```
Roles.GetRolesForUser( Membership.GetUser().UserName );
```

when i swap in System.Environment.UserName, the roles list comes back empty.

if i leave it as is and i set the auth cookie using 'true' as my second argument, it works fine.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie( user, true );
```

if i use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, the roles list is fine with the auth cookie set to true or false.

now, i understand the issue about performance. this is important to me. but i also need to ensure the application functions correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by 'invalid object'?  Null?

Comment: If you're just trying to get the username, you might want to consider grabbing System.Environment.UserName instead.  I'm not 100% sure, but I think that this property does NOT require a trip to the database, where Getuser() does.  If I'm correct, this would mean better performance and less overhead.

Comment: oh. well, what happens is that GetUser() returns something that is not a real object, then .GetName from that object throws a 'NullReferenceException' exception. i'll have a look at the System.Environment.UserName, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why can't you use

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

?

Comment: dunno. never programed asp.net c# before.. ;-) ... will give it a shot.

Comment: thanks andyc - do you know if this is a trip back to the db? seems to not be as 'Name' looks like a property (heh, which *shouldn't* go to the db, but you never know what evil lurks in the hearts of programmers.. ;-)

Comment: No, it has no trip back to the database. HttpContext.Current is effectively a wrapper for the current Http context.

Comment: i want to bump this up, but i don't have the creds. +3 in my book.. since this implementation, we have been testing the app and have yet to have a login fail due to null object.

Answer (score 2):

`Membership.ValidateUser()` returns `true` or `false` whether the user is valid or not, but it does not sign them in.

**[Membership.ValidateUser Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser.aspx)**

> Verifies that the supplied user name and password are valid.

Try this instead:

```
bool createPersistentCookie = true; // remember me?

if (Membership.ValidateUser(user, passwd)) {
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user, createPersistentCookie);
    if (FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(user, createPersistentCookie) == null)
        throw new SecurityException("Authentication persistence failed");

    Membership.GetUser().UserName; // should have a value now
}
else
{
    // invalid login
}
```

Comment: as of now, i call FormsAuthentication.SetAUthCookie( user, *false* ) .. is the 'false' tripping me up? i just changed the false to true and it seems to work every time. i'll look up the dox to see what this really means.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the system.web.security methods to authenticate users to use web service methods.
I don't use the cookie authentication in FormsAuthentication at all.

I have to set up the roles associated with the web service methods in the web.config file

```
  <add name="rule1" url="~/WebService.svc/rest/help" method="*" role="?"/>      
  <add name="rule1" url="~/WebService.svc/rest/Method1" method="*" role="service"/>
  <add name="rule1" url="~/WebService.svc/rest/Method2" method="*" role="service"/>...
```

Then the following code is called every time a request comes in to verify the authentication:

```
Membership.ValidateUser(username, password); //Validates user credential
Roles.IsUserInRole(username, "/WebService.svc/rest/Method2"); //Verifies User is authorised for method in question
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using cookies to persist user credentials? If so.. I believe the following authentication steps should be taken:

1. call ***ValidateUser*** to check for correct credentials.. as you already do
2. call ***FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie*** to to set the authentication cookie
3. ***Response.Redirect***( "Some home page or another "); will refresh the credentials cookies and get you a valid user object

Hope it helps

Comment: the method if ( validate user ) { FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie( user, false ); } ... is this what you mean? the GetUser() is called *after* all this happens.